# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when trying to run Jar job on Elastic MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

What should I change to fix following error:

I'm trying to start a job on Elastic Mapreduce, and it crashes every time with message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: iataho.mapreduce.NewMaxTemperatureMapper
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:831)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:577)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: iataho.mapreduce.NewMaxTemperatureMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:778)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:829)
... 4 more
```

The class **NewMaxTemperatureMapper** is declared and I've checked, it is included in the jar, which is than located at s3. 
Here's the code for all app classes:

**NewMaxTemperature.java:**

```
package iataho.mapreduce;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class NewMaxTemperature {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: NewMaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(123);
        }
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(NewMaxTemperature.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(NewMaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(NewMaxTemperatureReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(NewMaxTemperatureReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

**NewMaxTemperatureReducer.java:**

```
package iataho.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class NewMaxTemperatureReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (IntWritable value : values) {
        maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
}
}
```

**NewMaxTemperatureMapper.java:**

```
package iataho.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class NewMaxTemperatureMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private static final int    MISSING = 9999;

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    String year = line.substring(15, 19);
    int airTemperature;
    if (line.charAt(87) == '+') { // parseInt doesn't like leading plus
                                    // signs
        airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(88, 92));
    } else {
        airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(87, 92));
    }
    String quality = line.substring(92, 93);
    if (airTemperature != MISSING && quality.matches("[01459]")) {
        context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));
    }
}
}
```

I've made the jar file with which I'm getting this crash avaliable here: [download jar](http://www.iathao.com/jars/test.jar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the jars you are including when executing the application. Add more info to the question about this please.

===

Ok. The problem was that I've used eclipse option "Package libraries into generated JAR". I changed it to "Extract generated libraries into generated JAR", and now it works fine

Comment: all jars have been compiled into a single executive jar with eclipse; Anyway, it can't find one of MY classes, which is public and in the same package as the main class

Comment: I've put the jar online for the case anyone would like to have a look at it

Comment: The link downloads test.zip with several jars and your classes, not the jar you build. If any class is missing, please check the build jar configuration as some classes could be not included in the jar accidentally.

Comment: this is the jar which I had put on the s3 to be used by EMR. Should I had put something else instead?

Comment: Not sure which jar structure you should follow with EMR.

Comment: According to what I see, the main() gets executed alright; then when it gets to job.setMapperClass(NewMaxTemperatureMapper.class) it won't find it

Comment: Actually, when I think about it some more - the input file is in GZ format. When I was creating the app, I was expecting hadoop to extract it automatically. Will it do that? If not, how should I modify the code to use GZ codec to extract lines from the file inside and send them to the reducer?

Comment: GZIP is not same as ZIP. Java by default support ZIP compressions, but not GZIP. JAR are ZIP files so try to use always ZIP in java world.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3336/discussion-between-arsen-zahray-and-david-olivan-ubieto)